# The flipping cards on click function doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Its simply a 9 card game which you have to get 3 aces to win, i am using a click event listener to flip the cards and then comparing them together, it works fine on pc while on mobile the cards donot flip.
Here is the code.
https://codepen.io/ahmedroushdi/pen/JjZQEwJ
The images doesnot show up on codepen because they are saved on pc but the cards is flipped.

Well, I have tried another way to flip the cards in the old version i just change the image but now i have positioned them on top of each other and when you click on the card where its backface is hidden the other card "face" shows up and i have adjusted the -webkit- transform for it and no result also i have added another event listener for the touch effect on mobile phones and it didn't make any difference so i don't have any other solutions.

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card-toFlip");
let cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree;

function flipCard(e) {
  let clickedCard = e.path[1];

  if (clickedCard != cardOne) {
    clickedCard.classList.add('is-flipped');

    if (!cardOne) {
      cardOne = clickedCard;
      let cardOneImg = cardOne.querySelector('.card-front').getAttribute('alt');
      if (cardOneImg != "ace") {
        setTimeout(() => {
          cardOne.classList.toggle('vibration');
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
          cardOne.classList.remove('is-flipped');
        }, 3000);
      }
      return
    }

    if (!cardTwo) {
      cardTwo = clickedCard;
      let cardOneImg = cardOne.querySelector('.card-front').getAttribute('alt');
      let cardTwoImg = cardTwo.querySelector('.card-front').getAttribute('alt');
      if (cardOneImg === "ace" && cardTwoImg != "ace") {
        setTimeout(() => {
          cardOne.classList.add('vibration');
          cardTwo.classList.add('vibration');
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
          cardOne.classList.remove('is-flipped');
          cardTwo.classList.remove('is-flipped');
        }, 3000);
      }
      return
    }
    cardThree = clickedCard;


    let cardOneImg = cardOne.querySelector('.card-front').getAttribute('alt');
    let cardTwoImg = cardTwo.querySelector('.card-front').getAttribute('alt');
    let cardThreeImg = cardThree.querySelector('.card-front').getAttribute('alt');
    matchCards(cardOneImg, cardTwoImg, cardThreeImg);

  }
};

cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
});
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('touchstart', flipCard);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 10% 20%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(64, 64, 64) 90.2%);
}

header {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.headline {
  font-size: 5vw;
  margin-top: 5vw;
}

header p {
  padding-top: 1vw;
}

.sub-text {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.cards-background {
  margin-top: 6vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-toFlip {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-toFlip .card-back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  margin: 0vw 0.5vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  width: 130px;
  height: 190px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-toFlip.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  animation: normal 0.5s ease;
}

.card-toFlip .card-front {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  left: 3%;
  margin: 0vw 0.5vw;
  width: 130px;
  height: 190px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cards-background img:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-toFlip.is-flipped.vibration {
  animation: vibration 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

@keyframes vibration {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(-13px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-13px, 0, 0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateX(13px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(13px, 0, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(-8px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-8px, 0, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(8px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(8px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  .headline {
    margin: 10vw 3vw 0vw;
  }
  .cards-background {
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 13vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
  }
  .card-toFlip {
    width: 19%;
  }
  .card-toFlip .card-front {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    left: 15%;
  }
  .card-toFlip .card-back {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    position: static;
    margin-bottom: 11vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  .headline {
    margin: 10vw 3vw 0vw;
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
  header p {
    margin: 0.5vw;
  }
  .sub-text {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  .cards-background {
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 13vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
  }
  .card-toFlip {
    width: 30%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-style: none;
  }
  .card-toFlip .card-front {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    left: 25%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .card-toFlip .card-back {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    position: static;
    margin-bottom: 11vw;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .headline {
    margin: 10vw 3vw 0vw;
  }
  .sub-text {
    font-size: 2vw;
  }
  .cards-background {
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 8vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
  }
  .card-toFlip {
    width: 30%;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: none;
  }
  .card-toFlip .card-front {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    left: 25%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .card-toFlip .card-back {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    position: static;
    margin-bottom: 5vw;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<main style="height:100vh">
  <div class="cards-background">
    <div class="card1 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/2_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="2">
    </div>
    <div class="card2 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back">
      <img src="images/ace_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="ace">
    </div>
    <div class="card3 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/3_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="3">
    </div>
    <div class="card4 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/4_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="4">
    </div>
    <div class="card5 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/ace_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="ace">
    </div>
    <div class="card6 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/5_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="5">
    </div>
    <div class="card7 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/6_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="6">
    </div>
    <div class="card8 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/7_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="7">
    </div>
    <div class="card9 card-toFlip" id="card">
      <img src="images/back.png" class="card-back" id="card-back">
      <img src="images/ace_of_clubs.png" class="card-front" id="card-number" alt="ace">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a tough one to read but if I'm gonna guess, I'd say your error comes from this rule:

```
.card-toFlip .card-front {
    width: 130px;
    height: 190px;
    left: 25%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

under the `@media (max-width:767px)` media query.

The fact that you said max-width 767px means that style will affect all devices between 767px and 0 (if it's possible to have devices with 0 width). Meaning this style will affect mobile devices as well, since most of their widths fall below 767px.

Now, because the styles in that media query will take precedence over all the previously defined styles, the card front would always be flipped 180deg even though you add the `is-flipped` class. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I understand what you mean and sorry i am new to web development, but i couldn't understand why does this line "the one which rotates the card' makes a problem on mobile and not on the pc?

Comment: Oh what line is that?

Comment: What i have understood from your answer is that the transform: rotateY(180deg) is the reason why the cards donot flip because it makes front card always flipped. Am i right?

Comment: Oh yes that is correct.

Comment: So you're asking why that is a problem. Well where's something called [specifity in css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp). Specifity decides what styles take precedence over the other in css. Rules defined under media queries, generally take precedence over rules that aren't defined within media queries(with some exceptions of course). 
Try to follow that specifity link to better understand what I'm talking about